# Nutch 2.3.1 not crawling internal links without domain name

Tags: nutch

I have got a nutch set in place to crawl many websites at once, but for one site specifically and because of internal links like href="a link without a domain name" nutch could n't see through these urls,
below is the nutch-site

```
conf/regex-urlfilter.txt
# skip file: ftp: and mailto: urls
-^(file|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to  break loops
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# accept anything else 
+.
```

I changed the default nutch-defaults.conf

```
<property>
<name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
<value>true</value> <!-- do not leave the seeded domains (optional) -->
</property>
```

can somebody tell me what should I do.

Comment: The question is not clear... do you want to crawl internal links or not?

Comment: I want to crawl internal links but nutch doesn't detect those who have no domain name included in the href, take a lookat my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have got links that has no domain name, they are links of the same site example suppose we have href='www.site.com/linktext', in my case, I have got href='linktext'. Nutch did not see those links at all, it only detects those that contain domain name.

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I am facing a similar issue. I am trying to crawl buzzfeed and it's not able to get relative urls. There are no documents created while updating the database i.e. during the updatedb phase.